# Why does macOS 10.13 suddenly ask for a PIN instead of password for login?

Tags: macos, login, login-screen

When I have to enter my credentials, my Mac, which runs macOS 10.13 High Sierra, asks for a PIN instead of my password.

This has happened several times within the last months. The only solution I have is to force a shutdown (by pressing the power button)  and restart. With this procedure, my MacBook asks for my password again.

It's all confusing. I have never setup a PIN. Note: It is not the screen I would get if I lock my MacBook through Find my Mac.

[image]

Unfortunately, the only search results with `PIN` and `Macbook` is related to Find my Mac... I hope someone can help me by referring to the screenshot above.

What is this PIN and why is macOS asking for it? How can I prevent macOS from asking for a PIN?

Comment: Do you have a CAC (Common Access Card) reader attached to your MacBook?

Comment: No, I don't have a CAC reader.

Comment: Have you ever locked this MB with iCloud Find my Mac? Do you use two-factor authentication on your Apple ID? [This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7748012) at Apple Discussions has more clues.

Comment: I do have a Yubikey but it was not in the USB slot and never used for MacOS. I am using it for 2-factor authentication on the internet.

Comment: And I disabled 2-factor authentication for my Apple ID online. I was assuming that.

Comment: I would say it's your AppleID passcode. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have your Yubi key in the USB port at some point, put the Yubi key in and enter your Yubi Pin this will unlock your screen

Comment: But what do I do if I don't have my Yubi key around? This looks like a bug. If the key is not in, it should not ask for the PIN. Only when the key is inserted should the PIN be asked for.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer It is a bug. The behavior is as if the Yubikey is inserted, even if it isn’t. I had installed the software, then removed it and it still asks, occasionally. I don't know if the bug is in MacOS or if there’s a remnant Yubi driver hanging around.

Comment: NOPE!  My Yubikey PIN did nothing.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this. I didn't have a Yubi key attached but I had a code signing USB dongle attached to my hub. I was trying to figure out why it was only happening when I was connected to my external monitor (via the hub) and that's why. I unplugged the code signing USB dongle from the hub and presto, it returned to saying "Touch ID or Enter Password". Thank you for this!

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be a bug in either MacOS or the Yubico software. Even after removing the Yubikey profile, the system will occasionally lock the user out, requiring the Yubikey and the PIN.

The solution is to remove the specific related hashes from MacOS (from https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016649059):

1. Open Terminal.
2. Run: `sc_auth list [username]`

   - ex: `sc_auth list john`
3. Highlight and copy (Command+C) the hash listed for your user.
   If multiple YubiKey smart cards are paired with your account and you aren't sure which hash is which, you can check the hash of a particular YubiKey by running `sc_auth identities` with the key in question plugged in.
4. Run: `sc_auth unpair -h [hash]`

   - ex: `sc_auth unpair -h 5A596665D4BF7AE30A0830BFE129768738102C5001C65B57`

Comment: Thanks! I'd love to be able to use my yubikey for auth, but the fact that it then arbitrarily requires it *somethings when I haven't even had the yubikey plugged in since it last worked without* is beyond merely frustrating.  Hopefully this will solve it

Answer (score 2):

I run into this, too, with Big Sur (and earlier versions of MacOS).  I've found that I can work around it by

- clicking the "Switch User" thing at the bottom of the screen
- clicking my face when it appears
  At this point I'm presented with a proper "Password" entry, that works fine.

However:

Some other prompts don't let me work around it that way:

- Prompts from clicking the lock in System Preferences) let me use Touch ID, which works fine; but
- Prompts which pop up when I try to install software that needs Admin access have no such workaround.  I assume that, to install that sort of software, I'll need to fully log out and log back in (I haven't yet tried that).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than shutting down my Mac, I was able to switch to the Fast User Switching screen, and then went back to my own account without switching to a new user.  This time it accepted my password (while previously it would not, even though the text said that my password would work in contradiction to the placeholder text in the password field which said "PIN").

I tried taking screenshots to show the process, but alas none of them are available now that I'm logged in.

Whether Yubikey is to partly to blame—as speculated in another answer—I don't know.  But Apple is absolutely to blame:  either they are the sole source of the bug OR they are responsible for making it possible for a Yubikey bug to cause login failures.  In either case that is an absolutely unforgivable sin!

Answer (score -1):

You paired your key at some point with macOS.

Open Terminal and unpair it:

```bsh
sudo /usr/sbin/sc_auth unpair -u YourUserName
```

or simply

```bsh
sudo /usr/sbin/sc_auth unpair
```

Take out your key if you have it plugged in and reboot.

Your key should be unpaired from your username. Remember you don't have to pair your key to use it. You only have to pair it if you want to use it for macOS authentication.

Comment: Nope. I had already removed it. Now that command just responds with "No such key: AuthenticationAuthority".
This question is about when the PIN prompt appears randomly after a while.

Answer (score -1):

Mac OS has detected you have an e-signature installed probably ( on a flash drive for example ) - that is the pin it is referring to. Enter your electronic signature pin.

Comment: This just repeats the accepted answer.