# Why does macOS 10.14.6 suddenly ask for a PIN to download software?

Tags: install

downloaded software three days ago to run a CAC reader. No issues. Working. Now, the reader isn't working. So i'm reinstalling. keeps asking me for PIN to install software. Used password (have full admin rights) and Apple ID. Nothing is working. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does macOS 10.13 suddenly asks for a PIN instead of password for login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336165/why-does-macos-10-13-suddenly-asks-for-a-pin-instead-of-password-for-login)

Comment: Do you have a two factor authentication device like a keyfob with a passcode or a USB "token" attached?